# html5 video subtitle position + fullscreen

Tags: html, video, position, fullscreen, subtitle

I want to make a HTML5 video with multiple text at the same time.
The text should be shown on various positions on the video (at the same time) with different css layout (text color, font, shadow)
I tried this tutorial http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/01/popcorn-popup-popup-videos-video-annotations-bring-me-back-to-data/
The problem is that I can't see the text in fullscreen. The text size should also be sized to the size of the video, so if the video is on fullscreen the text should be bigger.
Does someone has a tutorial or example how I can do this?
It should work in Browsers like Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari (iOS)
Thanks for help